# Folder for temporary files creation in android, Why does /data/local/tmp doesn't work for me?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to create a temporary file in /data/local/tmp directory. The path is correct and I have added permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_PERMISSION also. But still I get an error from native code saying that file can't be created.

The code is as below.

```
File *file = fopen("mytxt.txt", "/data/local/tmp/");
```

The return value file always contains a null value and no file is created. Is there anything else needed to do?

Is there any other temporary folder that i can use for this purpose in android?

Thanks for any help that i can get.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The second parameter passed to fopen() is incorrect. That parameter should be an opening mode, not a directory path. See the man page of fopen.

Answer (score 3):

You can't access the /data folder unless your phone is rooted.

I'm not sure about the NDK, but there's a method in the SDK to get the cache directory

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getCacheDir%28%29

There's probably the same thing in the NDK.

Comment: sorry for novice question. What do you mean by phone is rooted. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: You don't have permissions to access the data folder unless you specifically gave root privileges to your phone.

Comment: /data is inaccessible without root, but /data/local/tmp is. Directories in Linux are accessible even if you don't have permissions to open their parent directory.

Comment: In Android, /data has a mode ending --x, which allows all users to "enter the directory and access files and directories inside".  It lacks the "r" bit so it is not possible to "list the files within the directory."  see e.g., http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/21252

Comment: To further clarify: To access a subdirectory, you need the "execute" permission on the ancestor directories (as well as the subdirectory itself) but don't need "read" or "write" permission.