# android application is getting lost its files

Tags: android

I have an app on Google Play. In the last few months I started getting complaints from users. The application loses its files and local data. In the past we didn't have such problems and the problem does not available on my test devices. The problem is available on Galaxy Core Prime.

How the program works:

1. When user logs in , data is kept in the file in the current directory
2. Downloaded operational files are also kept in the current folder.

`getAppContext().getSharedPreferences()` to write the data file
The application can't find the files on app next run.

The only thing I changed is the build version (from 10 to 14 API level)

What can be a reasons of this? can it be related to the build version?

Comment: Keep on mind that if you are saving data on SharedPreferences when the user clean the cache the data stored will be cleaned =(

Comment: @Elenasys, are you sure Prefs will be removed if cache is cleared ?? Prefs are stored in /data/data/package.name/.. not in /cache

Comment: yes! make a test I have posted an answer.

Comment: @Elenasys, Yes I know that, there are many apps which are cleaning the cache for some "performance" such as CCleaner, CleanMaster, etc. The problem is that I don't have any information about user apps and if it is true, how can I avoid this problem

Comment: I've found this link
http://stackoverflow.com/a/4864957/5682557

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that the preferences can be removed manually with:

`Settings` -> `Applications` -> `Manage applications` -> app -> `Clear data`.

Unfortunatelly this could be happen. Nowadays some users install apps to clean cache for release some of space.

Comment: is there a way to keep somewhere the files or copies ? somewhere different from cache ...